# Can I use StackOverflow formatting in HTML?

Tags: html, markdown

I am creating a website and would like to add a few StackOverflow-esque markup. For instance,

```
Code that can
take up multiple lines
elegantly,
```

> Blockquotes easily added,

and et cetera.

Is this just a lot of CSS, (that I will code if I have to) or can I integrate a StackOverflow markdown into my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Undoubtedly *YES*

`Stack Overflow` use `markdown` and There are many libraries for implementing `markdown`, for example many developers suggest you to use [`showdown`](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown), I prefer to use [`remarkable`](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/remarkable) but I suggest at first investigate about them.

I proffer to you read [awesome article about `markdown`](https://css-tricks.com/choosing-right-markdown-parser/) libraries and choose the best one for your case.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at adding what's known as a 'markdown' library.  There are plenty out there that all follow the same general syntax, I personally use Showdown: http://showdownjs.com/.